# MongoDb query: 2 milion query in DB OR 200 query in chunks of 10000. Which one is better for performance?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need some advice in a mongodb database query.

I have more than 2 million of data in my DB. I want to compare those records with one CSV file, which have 2 million records.

so I have two options:

1. I get one record from CSV and search in DB with 2 million data.in this case i am making 2 million query in database.
2. the second option is that, i can make 200 queries. in each query i can bring only 10000 data in a chunk from DB and compare that records with CSV file using hashmap and loop (in memory comparison).

i am using node.js and mongoose.js npm module.

which option is good performance wise?.

for example:

**1) first scenario:** (SMS transaction table, csv contains report from gateway provider i want to match it with DB)

*CSV contains following data:*

transaction_id, phone_number

*MongoDB documents contain the following data:*

phone_number, transaction_id or combined_field(phone_number+"-"+transaction_id)

**combined_field is a combination of phone_number and transaction_id which is separated by "-" (dash).

**The result I want something like this:** how many records from CSV which do not exist in DB

**2) second scenario** (for contact table, the user is uploading contact from csv)

*CSV contains following data*:

first_name, last_name, email, phone

*MongoDB data contains following data:*

first_name, last_name, email = [{value: "xyz@mail.com", is_primary: true/false}], phone = [{value: "1234567890", is_primary: true/false}]

**The result I want something like this:** contact is not represented in DB then prepare obj and insert in the database.

Comment: What the heck is a "lac"? Would you like to get your answer in Mandarin or German ;) ?

Comment: that was mu bad sorry. check updated question :p

Comment: Definitely option 2.

Comment: Second options is best. see the response time of both queries for 1000 data 1 to 1000 and 200 to 1000 data

Comment: import CSV to mongo db, compare collections.

Comment: @AlexBlex can you please tell me in detail, like how do i compare collections?

Comment: Depends on what results you need. intersection, difference, complement?

Comment: @AlexBlex can you give me any link or tutorial or sample code? I appreciate your effort.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic* I am happy to give a proper answer here if you explain what you are trying to achieve.  "*I want to compare*" tells nothing of the criteria nor the aim of comparison - do you need a list of identical documents in both collections, a list of documents that don't exists in one of them, a list of documents that have common properties but are not exact copy etc?. Please update the question with details.

Comment: @AlexBlex I have explained in details see my updated question. csv data is not same as mongodb documents.

Comment: Sorry mate, but it is still not clear what you expect from the comparison. Is the process of comparing records your final goal and you are not interested in the results? In fact your update raises even more questions. If it is "one CSV file", how do you have 2 scenarios with different data structures?

Comment: @AlexBlex i have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

The title is a typical example of [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so the answer is for 2 actual questions.

## 1. How many records from CSV which do not exist in DB

Use [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) to load data to a temporary collection in mongodb when it comes from the gateway provider, then count the difference using [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup) stage of aggregation framework.

Example:

- collection X - the base collection
- collection Y - the temporary collection from imported CSV

The query:

```
db.Y.aggregate([
    {
       $lookup:
         {
           from: "X",
           let: { key: { $concat: [ "$phone_number", "-", "$transaction_id" ] } },
           pipeline: [ { $match:{ $or:[
               { combined_field: "$$key"},
               { $expr: { $eq: [ "$$key", { $concat: [ "$phone_number", "-", "$transaction_id" ] } ] } }
           ] } } ],
           as: "exist"
         }
    },
    { $match: { exist: { $size: 0 } } },
    { $group: { _id: null, cnt: {$sum: 1} } }
])
```

returns number in the question.

## 2. Document is not represented in DB then prepare and insert in the database

Parse the CSV and [upsert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html) all documents.

Example:

- collection X - the base collection
- csvDoc - the javascritp document from a single CSV line

The query:

```
db.X.update(
    { first_name : csvDoc.first_name, last_name : csvDoc.last_name },
    { 
        $addToSet: { 
            email: { value: csvDoc.email, is_primary: true/false },
            phone : { value: csvDoc.phone, is_primary: true/false }
        },
        $setOnInsert: { first_name : csvDoc.first_name, last_name : csvDoc.last_name }, 
    }, 
    { upsert: true } 
)
```

it will add new documents if there is nothing with given first_name and last_name, or add email and phone to the arrays otherwise.

You can use [bulk writes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.upsert/) to speed it up a little by batching up to 1000 documents in a single command.

Comment: thank you for your answer i will test out your code and will let you know here. Thank you so much for your time.